# Google recaptcha no data on admin panel

Tags: django, admin, recaptcha

I have problem with google recaptcha, I saw other, older, similar topics, but they were slightly different, and outdated, so I decided to add new one.

I added google recaptcha to my django project (version 2 to one form for now). My adjango app works on localhost (for now), so I generated keys from google, added 127.0.0.1 as domain and used this: https://github.com/praekelt/django-recaptcha steb by step to add recaptcha v2.

Everything works (from user's side), I cannot post form if recaptcha is not clicked, I have to choose pictures if I spam too much etc ... Everything looks fine, but on google recaptcha admin side I hace only 3 requests shown, marked as "No CAPTCHa", and information "We detected that your site isn't verifying reCAPTCHA solutions. This is required for the proper use of reCAPTCHA on your site. Please see our developer site for more information." above.

I'm confused, becouse from one side: I made much more requests, I made dozen-or-so accounts, and around the same number of tests where I clicked recaptcha, but not created account, so there should be much more requests, from the oter side: everything works fine, I can not log in without captcha, I have to choose images if I spam (make many accounts in short period of time).

I'm doing it for the first time, so my question is - is this normal? Do I have to wait some time? Or is it possible, that I've done something wrong (I've done everything like in tutorial - step by step, and website worked well before, I've tested it, so it is this is unlikely) and captcha still works, but not fully? Is there a way to test website what runs on localhost if recaptcha works, without writing bot on my own?

Answer (score 1):

You are only using ReCaptcha in the frontend. In the backend you are not verifying whether the user actually passed ReCaptcha or not, you are just relying on Javascript to prevent somebody from submitting a form.

This is very bad because somebody can just open up Developer Console on their computer, delete Recaptcha and then spam your website as much as they want. And this is why you are getting the warning. You should be checking with Google on the backend whether somebody really passed a ReCaptcha test or not when they submitted the form so they can't do this.